# How to get hastahg, username tweets using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I written script for tweepy, where when I enter keyword like `bse`, `nse` it searches these keywords.

But when I enter hashtag `#bse`, `#nse` or user name `@skirani` , `@mukund` it gives no result.

I tried with both result_type, `recent` as well `popular`, no change. Is there any other result type?

```
def getTweets(self, data):
    import pdb
    # pdb.set_trace()
    tweets = {}
    if "query" in data:
        tweets = self.twitter_api.search(data['query'], result_type='recent' )
        # print type(tweets)
        result = tweets['statuses']
        count = 1
        for val in result:
            print count
            print val['text']
            count += 1
            print 
    return tweets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy requires that search entities are [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  That means that `@` needs to be `%40` and `#` must be `%23`

A simple way to do this in Python is:

```
import urllib2
search = urllib2.quote("@skirani")
```